# Java Stack into GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, stack

right now I'm studying my Diploma in Programming, we have a set task of creating a calculator to calculate the total, average, a counter, the maximum and minimum entered, an undo button and a clear button. I have everything done, including the undo button, but my lecturer has set an extra credit opportunity, by adding a stack function into the undo method. I've worked out how to push the objects, but I'm unsure on how to pop the object and add the requested object into my GUI. I understand this isn't exactly required, but I want to do this for the rest of my life, so I'm really trying hard. If anyone is able to help me, my source file is below.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class DataPanel extends JPanel {
    ArrayList<Data> dataStore = new ArrayList<Data>();
    Stack dataStack = new Stack(); 

    private double _number, _oldNumber;
    private double _total, _oldTotal;
    private int _count, _oldCount;
    private double _average, _oldAverage;
    private double _min, _oldMin;
    private double _max, _oldMax;

    private JTextField _inField = new JTextField();
    private JTextField _totalField = new JTextField(); 
    private JTextField _averageField = new JTextField(); 
    private JTextField _minField = new JTextField(); 
    private JTextField _maxField = new JTextField(); 
    private JTextField _countField = new JTextField(); 

    public DataPanel() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 2, 1, 1));
        add(new JLabel("Number"));
        add(_inField);
        _inField.addActionListener(new InFieldListener());

        add(new JLabel("Total"));
        add(_totalField);   
        _totalField.setEditable(false);

        add(new JLabel("Count"));
        add(_countField);
        _countField.setEditable(false);

        add(new JLabel("Average"));
        add(_averageField);
        _averageField.setEditable(false);

        add(new JLabel("Maximum"));
        add(_maxField);
        _maxField.setEditable(false);

        add(new JLabel("Minimum"));
        add(_minField);
        _minField.setEditable(false);
    }

    public void clear() {
      _total = 0;
      _count = 0;
      _average = 0;
      _max = 0;
      _min = 0;

        _inField.setText("");
        _totalField.setText("");
        _countField.setText("");
        _averageField.setText("");
        _maxField.setText("");
        _minField.setText("");
    }

    public void undo() {
       /*_number = _oldNumber;
        _total = _oldTotal;
        _count = _oldCount;
        _average = _oldAverage;
        _max = _oldMax;
        _min = _oldMin;

        _inField.setText(String.valueOf(_number));
        _totalField.setText(String.valueOf(_total));
        _countField.setText(String.valueOf(_count));
        _averageField.setText(String.valueOf(_average));
        _maxField.setText(String.valueOf(_max));
        _minField.setText(String.valueOf(_min));*/

        /*int size = dataStore.size();
        dataStore.remove(size-1);*/
    }

    private class Data {
        private Data(double _number, double _total, int _count, double _average, double _max, double _min) {
          _number = _number;
          _total = _total;
          _count = _count;
          _average = _average;
          _max = _max;
          _min = _min;
       }
   }


    private class InFieldListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(_inField.getText().equals("exit")) {
                System.exit(0);
            }       
            try {
                  _number = Double.parseDouble(_inField.getText());
                  _inField.setText("");

                /*_oldNumber = _number;
                _oldTotal = _total;
                _oldAverage = _average;
                _oldCount = _count;
                _oldMax = _max;
                _oldMin = _min;*/

                  _count++;

              if(_count == 1) {
                _min = _number;
                _max = _number;
              } else if(_number >= _max) {
                _max = _number;
              } else if(_number <= _min) {
                _min = _number;
              }

                  _total += _number;
                  _average = _total/_count;

              _totalField.setText(String.valueOf(_total));
             _countField.setText(String.valueOf(_count));
             _averageField.setText(String.valueOf(_average));
             _maxField.setText(String.valueOf(_max));
             _minField.setText(String.valueOf(_min));

             //dataStore.add(new Data(_number, _total, _count, _average, _max, _min));
             dataStack.add(new Data(_number, _total, _count, _average, _max, _min));

         } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
           System.out.println("There was a problem: " + nfe);
           _inField.setText("");
         }
        }
    }
}
```

All of the syntax that is surrounded by /* */ are the original undo method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code:

```
dataStack.add(new Data(_number, _total, _count, _average, _max, _min));
```

should be `push()` instead of `add()`.

Then in `undo()` you can call dataStack.pop() and cast the object you get back from that to a `Data`. (Alternative: use generics)

Then you take out each of that `Data`'s members to restore the instance-variables `_number` and so on.

EDIT:  > How do I scan out though?

For every click on the undo-Button you only have to restore (=pop()) one Data-Object. You can then ask it for its variables and restore the DataPanel's variables with those. Example:

```
Data d = (Data)dataStack.pop();
_number = d._number;
...
```

Comment: Oops, I'm a bit of a moron for mistaking .push() for .add() haha.
but how do I actually scan it out? Just like a Scanner? (while(scan.hasNext())?

Comment: Moron? No! It is just experience through practice, keep going

Comment: How do I scan out though? I've got the idea that it's like using a File Scanner, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Have replied to this comment by editing my answer because i had to place some code

Comment: Okay, maybe not so easy. I added the code, and expanded it to all of the variables, except now when I click undo, it sends all of the JTextFields back to 0.0. Not sure if I've made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Hmm, dont know, can't see. Could you post all your code to pastebin.com so we can help you debug?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7628/discussion-between-nathan-kreider-and-eznme)